# Django session is not being persisted and cookie is not being set when using Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

**Django 3.0.6, Channels 2.4, Channels-Redis 2.4**

**I'm developing on WSL/Ubuntu 18.04 using runserver and channels_redis**

I am writing a chat application, and the whole app is working fine except for this problem.  I assign a random username to non-authenticated users.  I save this username to `self.scope['session']` within the consumer.  For authenticated users, the `csrftoken` cookie and the `sessionid` cookie are being set correctly in the browser.  However, even though I both set and save a `scope['session']['user_name']` variable for non-authenticated users in the consumer's `connect` method, the session is not being saved in the `django_session` table and the `user_name` cookie is therefore not being set in the browser.  I am using an async consumer, and I am using the correct `database_sync_to_async` syntax to save the session as shown at the bottom of the first example code shown [here](http://await%20database_sync_to_async(self.scope[%22session%22].save)()).

Relevant code sections:

**consumers.py:**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from chat.models import *


class ChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    DIGITS = string.digits
    ANON_NUMBER_LENGTH = 7

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = f'chat_{self.room_name}'
        if not self.scope["user"].is_authenticated:
            if 'user_name' not in self.scope['session']:
                # Create user name session for anonymous user
                random_number = ''.join(random.choice(ChatConsumer.DIGITS) for i in range(ChatConsumer.ANON_NUMBER_LENGTH))
                self.scope['session']['user_name'] = f'Guest_{random_number}'
            await database_sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()
        elif 'user_name' in self.scope['session']:
            # Remove user_name from session if present
            self.scope['session'].pop('user_name')
            await database_sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()
        await self.accept()
```

**routing.py:**

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),    
})
```

The above `await database_sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()` statement is apparently being executed without error (a print statement just before it printed fine).  I even tried setting `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` to `True` as [noted here](http://await%20database_sync_to_async(self.scope[%22session%22].save)()) (though I didn't expect that to help), but the session is still not persisted.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So channels does not support setting cookies in websocket consumers... :( there is some open debate on even is browsers will respect cookies on websocket upgrade responses.

however if you ensure that the user already has a session (even if it is anonimuse) before they hit the websocket endpoint then you should (if your using a db backed session) be able to update it at any point (but you will not be able to set any cookies on the clients side).